# Retrieve All Content Areas in a Parent Folder

Tags: ampscript, ssjs, microsites, content-area

I've got a simple landing page that is serving as a content reference directory so I can easily look up all content areas without going through each folder. Unfortunately, the number of content areas has increased dramatically (1000+) and I'm looking for an easy way to dynamically display them on the microsite.

Is it possible, using ampscript or SSJS, to retrieve all content areas for a specific folder and not globally? I've got the code to do this with ampscript globally now but it has started to time out due to the large number of content areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was much easier to solve than I had thought. Just had to filter by Category ID.

`SET @fs = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
 SetObjectProperty(@fs, "Property", "CategoryID")
 SetObjectProperty(@fs, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
 AddObjectArrayItem(@fs, "Value", <CategoryID Value>)`

Comment: I wanted to list all content blocks within a folder. Is that possible by SSJS.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with SSJS. You'll need to make a REST API POST call to Marketing Cloud in order to query Content Builder assets by their category id. Property to filter on is Category.id. Here's a link to the API docs for more info, but you can also find a lot of examples of this on SE. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm